# Outlook VBA Item_add isn't working

Tags: vba, events, outlook

I have a **class module** as it follows:

```
Public WithEvents nItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub nItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    MsgBox Item.Subject
End Sub
```

And I know that in somewhere a value needs to be set for nItems, such as:

```
Set nItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
```

But the problem is that nItems loses its value after the procedure ends.
And thus, the event is not called by Outlook when I get a new message.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the *nItems* outside of the procedure.

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items 

Public Sub Initialize_handler() 
  Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items 
End Sub 

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) 
  Dim myOlMItem As Outlook.MailItem 
  Dim myOlAtts As Outlook.Attachments 
  Set myOlMItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
  myOlMItem.Save 
  Set myOlAtts = myOlMItem.Attachments 
  ' Add new contact to attachments in mail message 
  myOlAtts.Add Item, olByValue 
  myOlMItem.To = "Sales Team" 
  myOlMItem.Subject = "New contact" 
  myOlMItem.Send 
End Sub
```

Be aware, the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event is not fired when a large number of items are added to the folder at once (more than 16).

Also you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.